# VBA object required error when parsing value into array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, object

I get the 'Object Required' error when trying to parse a value from a list into an array. The weird thing is, is that I do it once and it works, but when I try and parse the second value with a different offset it gives me the 'Object Required' error.

```
Sub Run_Click()

Dim ArrVal() As Variant
Dim DateRange As Range
Dim ComValue() As Variant
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim numRow As Variant
Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Dim ConvertVal As String
Dim check As Variant
Dim DutyTest() As Variant


Set sh2 = Sheets(2)

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 7
    
    ReDim Preserve ComValue(1 To LastRow)
    ReDim Preserve ArrVal(1 To LastRow)
    ReDim Preserve DutyTest(1 To LastRow)
    
    Set DateRange = .Range("A" & 8 & ":A" & 7 + LastRow)
    
    i = 1
    Do While i <= LastRow
    If i > LastRow Then GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    For Each RowCount In DateRange
        'On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
        ComValue(i) = .Range("A" & i + 7).Value
        ConvertVal = CStr(ComValue(i))
        
        numRow = Application.Match(ConvertVal, sh2.Range("A1:A990000"), 0)
        ArrVal(i) = sh2.Range("A" & numRow).Offset(0, 2).Value
        DutyTest(i) = sht2.Range("A" & numRow).Offset(1, 1).Value
        
    
        If i = LastRow Then
        Range("B8").Resize(UBound(ArrVal), 1).Formula = Application.Transpose(ArrVal)
        
        End If
        
        i = i + 1
        
        
        
        
        Next RowCount
    Loop
    
ErrorHandler:
    End With
End Sub
```

The error is pulled on the `DutyTest(i)` line below the `ComValue(i)` line which gets returned fine. The only difference I can think of is that `ComValue(i)` is a percent that is returned, in the offset field for `DutyTest(i)` it should return a string instead, could that be causing the issue?

Comment: `sht2` is not the same with `sh2`. You should cultivate the habit to set `Option Explicit` on top of all used modules. In such a case, any typo will be automatically shown...

Answer (score 1):

You have written `sht2` as the sheet reference instead of `sh2`. This is the object reference error here, I think.

I believe it is good practice in VBA to enforce variable declaration with `Option Explicit`:

https://riptutorial.com/excel-vba/example/3554/always-use--option-explicit-

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/option-explicit-statement

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I went blind seemingly, awesome

Comment: No problem - I've indicated one way to avoid this by using option explicit (and how to turn it on automatically for all your modules going forward).